# Problem with separating strings in output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having problem with separating the output string with `,` and I need to put a bracket in the beginning and in the end and I need to put apostrophe `""` per string.

```
def friend(x):
    temp = ""
    for i in x:
        if (len(i)==4):
            temp += i
    x = temp    
    return temp
```

**Input:** ['Ryan', 'Joseph', 'Mark']

**My Output:** 'RyanMark'

**Expected Output:** ['Ryan', 'Mark']

Comment: Your question was unclear in the presentation of **Input** as `Ryan, Joseph, Mark`.  To get **My Output** as 'RyanMark', the the input must be a `list`.  The question has been edited to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm not understanding the question, but you could just print a list

```
def friend(x):
    return [n for n in x if len(n) == 4]

print(friend([ 'Ryan', 'Joseph', 'Mark' ]))  # ['Ryan', 'Mark']
```

But the issue with your code is that you are taking `"" + "Ryan" + "Mark"`. If you want apostrophes and the comma, then you would have to do something like

```
temp += "'{}', ".format(i)
```

Though, that would result in a trailing comma `'Ryan', 'Mark',` and you could `return "[{}]".format(temp)` to end up with `['Ryan', 'Mark', ]`

Ultimately, I think the instructions just want you to filter the list.

Answer (score 0):

This processing would be closer to the desired result if processed as a list, rather than a string.  Obviously your error is because you are concatenating the strings 'Ryan' and 'Mark' together.

```
def friend( name_list ):
    short_names = []                      # result is a list
    for name in name_list:
        if ( len( name ) == 4 ):
            short_names.append( name )    # add short name to list
    return short_names                    # return a list (could be empty)

...

friends_list = [ 'Ryan', 'Joseph', 'Mark' ]
print( str( friend( friends_list ) ) )
```

This code given a list of [ 'Ryan', 'Joseph', 'Mark' ], outputs the desired format - since this is default string-version of a list.

A much less read-able form is to put all the logic into a list-creation statement:

```
friends_list = [ name for name in friends_list if len( name ) == 4 ]
```

To go from a comma-delimited string of names, it's easy to use the `string.split()` function:

```
names = 'Ryan, Joseph, Mark'
name_list = names.split(', ')
```

which returns a list:

```
>>> names = 'Ryan, Joseph, Mark'
>>> name_list = names.split(', ')
>>> name_list
['Ryan', 'Joseph', 'Mark']
```

Comment: "A list of names for each name in the friend list, if the length of the name is 4" seems completely readable to me

Answer (score -1):

```
input = "Ryan, Joseph, Mark"
output = ['%s'%i for i in input.split(', ')]
```

so, result will be ['Ryan', 'Joseph', 'Mark']

Comment: The expected output doesn't have joseph

Comment: Try running it, It prints the result. @cricket_007

Comment: Please read the question again, and look at the expected output

Comment: That part is unclear about joseph not being in output.

Comment: Why? Given some input, he expects different output, not the same. Also, it looks like you've just assigned three variables here, not showing `print(output)`

Comment: that's pretty much self-explanatory that output contains the final result.